# user-input handling postgresql

Tags: postgresql, perl-module

I feel like I'm missing a very basic concept. I could use some clarification or reference material.

On my website, I have a user that enters text into an input box and submits that to the database to be stored. I insert that text into the database using a function in the code block below where `$conn->exec(query)` is from [Pg.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~mergl/pgsql_perl5-1.9.0/Pg.pm).

```
$conn->exec("select someFunc($mykey,'text to insert');");
```

Now, this works, but is vulnerable to a sql injection or even if a user enters a comma, it breaks.

I read about [DBD::Pg](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/DBD-Pg-2.16.1/Pg.pm) which has the `prepare` statement which seems what I want, but I could not find the equivalent of this for `Pg.pm`. Did I miss it?

If `Pg.pm` does not support `prepare`. Should I be using a perl module that supports the `prepare` statement? Or can I just follow the approach outlined at [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com/postgresql.html) with `quote_ident()` and `quote_literal` in my SQL functions that are inserting/updating user-input fields.

How should I be handling user-input in a safe way?

Comment: Don't use `Pg.pm`.  It is wildly outdated and obsolete.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut, That's what I was thinking (last version 2000-04-04), but I wasn't sure. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *not* just use `quote_ident` and `quote_literal`, because they're at the SQL level, applying to dynamic SQL invoked with `EXECUTE`. It won't do you any good when passing arguments into the function because the SQL string parsing (and SQL injection attack risk) occurs before the function is even executed with those arguments.

You *really* need either prepared statement support or a strong, secure literal escaping function that understands PostgreSQL literal quoting rules. If your database driver provides neither then is is unacceptably insecure and should be discarded in favour of one that does.

Comment: Are you aware of any such support for `Pg.pm`? Also, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I don't use Perl much and have never used `Pg.pm`, so no. Others might be. Why do you want to use it instead of `DBI` and `DBD::Pg` anyway?